# Is there A Possibility To Add A Shape Key Property With bpy.types.ShapeKey

Tags: python, properties

Recently I tried to add a API Property To ever shape key, like I can with `bpy.types.Object`.

However when I try to access it, I get the info, that the property is deferred and blender seems to see it as a function, despite the fact that I can access it, I can not show it in my UI or change it. When I try I get the error, that the property is a collection and read only.

Does anybody know how I can access it properly?

This works as expected:

```
bpy.types.Scene.auxNormalizedVector = StringProperty(
default="[]")
```

This does not:

```
bpy.types.ShapeKey.auxShowOptions = BoolProperty(
default = False)
```